# Is there a shortcut for creating a new file?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I haven't seen any shortcut for creating "A New Text Document" or any file. Is there any?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Windows 7 and earlier:
<kbd>Alt+F</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> works, regardless of whether the file or folder pane has focus.

Windows 8: This doesn't work in any more. <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd> works as long as the file pane has focus.

Windows 10: <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd> works as long as the file pane has focus *and no file is selected*. Press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>-<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to clear the selected files (thanks @RogUE).

Windows 10 2nd Method: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  This works in even if a file is selected:

Comment: This is the only built-in-solution I found for Win7. Still wonder why Microsoft has decided to use shortcut `w` for Ne`w`. Why not `n` to make it easy?

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV: Look at the underlined letters in the menu. “New” can’t be ‘N’ because ‘N’ is “Se `n` d to”. (And “Send to” can’t be ‘S’ because ‘S’ is “Create `s`hortcut”. And “Create shortcut” can’t be ‘C’ because ‘C’ is “`C`lose”.) ... (No relation to Ben.)

Comment: If a file or folder is selected, you could hit crtl+space to deselect it

Comment: @RogUE it works for only a certain file. When I enter a folder, select some files then do ctrl+space it only selects or deselects a certain file, not all the selected files, on Windows 10 that is.

Comment: thanks for Control + Spacebar combination to clear the selected files. I used Alt+Up to go up, then Enter to return the folder, so silly :).

Answer (score 18):

I wrote a script based on the suggestions to use AutoHotkey. If you want to change the `.txt` file extension, this requires `Hide extentions for known file types` to be **off**.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
#n:: ;If Windows+N is pressed in Windows Explorer
Send {Alt} ;Menu
Send f ;> File
Send w ;> New
Send t ;select Text Document
Send ^a ;select all
Exit
```

*If you need any help with AutoHotkey, let me know. :)*

Comment: Where does the limitation on the visible file name extensions come in?

Comment: @DanielBeck Studiohack merged two questions. The one that I originally answered asked if the file extension could be removed. Since we are using `.txt`, we should select the whole file name including `.txt`. I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks iglvzx! I added `Send {Delete}` because even though everything was selected, typing only deleted the part before the extension.

Comment: If you want to make it shorter and easier use this: `SendInput !fwt`

Comment: If you want to **rename** the file to what you have in the clipboard and **open** the file afterwards use this:
`SendInput !fwt
Sleep 100
SendInput ^a{backspace}^v{enter}{enter}{enter}`

Comment: you should provide complete explanation rather than just throwing some code without explanation. how to run this script? how this creates a new file, where?

Comment: It doesn't create the file for me. It just highlights the **+New** button on the menu bar. I'm on Windows 11.

Answer (score 5):

The following works under XP (I don't have Windows 7):

- make sure the Files (not Folders) pane has focus (<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> to get there).
- make sure no file is selected (press <kbd>CTRL+Space</kbd> to unselect one file if necessary).
- bring up either the File menu with <kbd>Alt+F</kbd> or the context menu with the context menu key or <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>W</kbd> for New, and <kbd>T</kbd> for Text Document.

Comment: This is a looong procedure. Something like Ctrl+Shift+T will do.

Comment: It works, but not if any other applications start adding to the file menu to interfere with the W shortcut e.g. WinMerge.

Comment: This still works under Windows 8. When other application add menu items with the W shortcut, you have to press the W key twice and submit with enter or right arrow key.

Comment: Alt+F, W, T works well and I've used it a long time in Windows XP, Vista and 7, no good in Win10.

Comment: Wow! [Shift]+[F10], [W] for New,
and [T] for Text Document works on Windows 10. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It may be possible with a [third party solution](http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php) (haven't tested it, [autokey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is famous too), since it's not available in [Windows 7's official keyboard shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts). You can create a new folder using `Ctrl+Shift+N` though.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following on my Swedish Windows 7 machine and it works good. No need to install third party.

1. Open folder
2. Press ALT-key to display menubar
3. A (Swe. Arkiv, Eng. File)
4. N (Swe. Nytt, Eng. New)
5. T (Swe. Textdokument, Eng. Textdocument)

Short:
ALT, A, N, T

Answer (score 1):

Right click (leave right click mouse button) then press 'W' (leave W) and finally press 'T' works with windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this autohotkey script for ages.

```
;   New text file

#IfWinActive AHK_CLASS #32770
    Capslock & f11::
#IfWinActive AHK_CLASS CabinetWClass
    Capslock & f11::

    ; make it work even though a file is previously selected
    Send {PgUp} ; Force select the first file 
    Send ^{Space} ; Clear the selection

    Sleep 250 ; Remove delay if not required
    Send {AppsKey} ; Menu key
    Send w ; New
    Send t ; Text Document
    return
#IfWinActive
```

- Works on file dialogs (save as / open file)
- Works even though a file is selected
- Works even though cursor is positioned off screen

Change "Capslock & f11" to your preferred shortcut.

---

To understand the syntax above, see below example,

```
;   Syntax - To have the same hotkey subroutine executed by more than one variant, the easiest way is to create a stack of identical hotkeys, each with a different #IfWin directive above it. For example:
    ;#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
    ;#z::
    ;#IfWinActive ahk_class WordPadClass
    ;#z::
    ;MsgBox You pressed Win+Z in either Notepad or WordPad.
    ;return
```

Hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#NoTrayIcon ; the process will not appear on windows taskbar on the right
#IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
^r:: ;
KeyWait Control 
Sleep 40
Send {Alt} ;
Sleep 40
Send {Enter};
Sleep 40
Send {Enter}
```

You need to create .ahk file with this script. Also, you need to check if it creates .txt file. For this, open windows explorer, press Alt, then press enter, and look how many times do you have to press Up arrow key to it to open .txt file. After that, copy or delete those two lines of code

```
Send {Enter};
Sleep 40
```

Don't forget to add this to your startup apps folder so that you don't have to open this script every time. You can do that:

- open the windows run app by pressing win+r
- type: shell:startup
- drag your .ahk script to this folder

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1 [FileAppend & GetActiveExplorerPath()]

#### @logic::

- `FileAppend , Text, Filename, Encoding`

  Writes text to the end of a file (first creating the file, if necessary).

  https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/FileAppend.htm
- `GetActiveExplorerPath()` & `GetExplorerPath(hwnd=0)`

  https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=69925

#### @reference::

- for details see [Create a text file with a keyboard shortcut in Windows Explorer](https://superuser.com/a/1369167/997622)

#### @source_code:: (basically same as the code in reference above)

```
; ######################################################

; ~~// https://superuser.com/questions/1091268/how-to-create-a-new-text-document-txt-file-by-a-hotkey
; ~~// https://superuser.com/questions/133175/is-there-a-shortcut-for-creating-a-new-file
; https://superuser.com/questions/1368969/create-a-text-file-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows-explorer

#If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") || WinActive("ahk_class ExploreWClass") || WinActive("ahk_class Progman") || WinActive("ahk_class WorkerW")

#n::
WinGet, active_id, ID, A
name := "NewTxtFile"
; WinActivate, ahk_id %active_id%
if (WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") || WinActive("ahk_class ExploreWClass")) { ; explorer
  FolderPath := getWindowsExplorerPath()
  FileAppend,, %FolderPath%\%name%.txt
  ; Run, %FolderPath%\%name%.txt
}
else if (WinActive("ahk_class Progman") || WinActive("ahk_class WorkerW")) { ; desktop
  FileAppend,, %A_Desktop%\%name%.txt
  ; Run, %A_Desktop%\%name%.txt
}
return 

; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=69925

getWindowsExplorerPath() {
  explorerHwnd := WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
  if (explorerHwnd) {
    ; i := 1
    for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows {
      ; ToolTip(++i)
      try {
        if (window.hwnd == explorerHwnd) {
          return window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

#If
```

#### @minor-comment::

- *this method may be recommended over the others, since `window navigation panel` & `popup context menu` are **unreliable** due to their: slowness (depends) / wait for popup / diff windows version hotkey are different / if your popup context menu has the hotkey conflict with others*
- (aga) this method may (or may not) be **slower** than others
- `FileAppend` does what it means -- so if you already have one file with the name `NewTxtFile.txt`, it **appends** to that file ...

  tweak the code if you need
- this **doesnt focus** to the file for editing the file name

### Method 2 [window navigation panel]

(another answer above) https://superuser.com/a/194593/997622

### Method 3 [popup context  menu]

(as many other answers talked) `SendInput, {AppsKey}wt`

Answer (score -1):

Get [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/).

Then you need create or find a script for shortcut binding. For more, read the [AHK tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/wiki/index.php?title=AHK_Tutorial).

Comment: So, how does this exactly solve the problem? Which script should they use?

Comment: @slhck I'm working on one! Shh.