# Windows 7 keyboard shortcut to create new file in Explorer

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a shortcut for creating a new file?](https://superuser.com/questions/133175/is-there-a-shortcut-for-creating-a-new-file)

*CTRL+SHIFT+N* creates a new folder in Explorer. Is there a shortcut for creating a new file (preferably with no default extension)? If there isn't, then is there a way to map a shortcut to do this?