# Language-independent keyboard shortcut to create a new text file

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, language

I need a locale-independent solution to create a new text file with a keyboard shortcut in Windows 7.

I've tried [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to create shortcut in Windows 7 for text file creation in current window of explorer like described in answer to [Is there a shortcut for creating a new file?](https://superuser.com/questions/133175/is-there-a-shortcut-for-creating-a-new-file).

However, the solution doesn't work on Russian systems because keyboard shortcuts depend on the UI language.

I faced the issue with Russian locale because I don't want to change my keyboard layout to Russian every time I want to use something like this:

```
Send {Alt} ;Menu
Send f ;> File
Send w ;> New
Send t ;select Text Document
Send ^a ;select all
```

In Russian locale I need to use Russian symbols instead of `f`, `w`, `t`, `a`, etc.

Is there a system language-independent solution for this?

Probably I need to get current location of opened explorer window and ... what? I don't want to send cmd command because I want to set file name in time I create file (not renaming it later with F2 key) and I don't have any other solution this moment.

Comment: Have you tried using Russian characters in the AutoHotkey script?

Comment: @gornostaj It's not a case because I work in multi-locale environment and want to use/share script between machines with both English (different types) and Russian locales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@**zubactik** Your need use the [virtual](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/blvkc.htm)/[scan](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_devices_keymap_vscan.html) codes of keys, instead names, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16594926)/[some my explanation](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=16053&start=240#19).