# Why can't I turn a folder into a file in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, filesystems, file-extension

Every time I need to create a text file in Windows I usually right-click inside a folder and select for any option from shortcut to a zip file and rename it's extension to ".txt" (I know that some of these options create garbage inside the txt but this is not a problem for me):

[image]

But for some reason if I try to do the same by creating a folder and rename it to "something.txt", it holds the folder format just staying as a folder:

[image]

Why this hapends and why I can't turn a folder into a txt or another file in Windows systems?

PS: If I could turn a folder into a file it would be much easier to create a txt file by pressing "Ctrl+Shift+N" renaming it to "file.txt". By the way, is there some keyboard shortcut that could help me to create a file?

Comment: Why not just go down the list and create a text file instead?  Takes you 2 extra seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows, a "[folder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/folders-faq#1TC=windows-7)" is a container of "files".

They are two different things and one cannot be changed into the other, especially not by just adding `.TXT` to the name. :)

More info: [Definition of: files vs. folders](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/60967/files-vs-folders)

> is there some keyboard shortcut that could help me to create a file?

See this other SU question: [Is there a shortcut for creating a new file?](https://superuser.com/questions/133175/is-there-a-shortcut-for-creating-a-new-file)