# How to create a new file using a shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I haven't seen any shortcut for creating "A New Text Document" or any file. Is there any?

([This question already exists 1:1](https://superuser.com/questions/133175/is-there-a-shortcut-for-creating-a-new-file), but for Windows 7 and the method there does not work for 10. As far as I know, this is the strange way to go if you have the same question for another system).

Comment: Could you be my guest and read the 3rd paragraph of the accepted answer in [this](http://superuser.com/q/133175/573485) question?

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz... I already tried that.