# How do I create a new folder using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know the shortcut key to create a new folder in Windows Explorer *and* in Finder?

Also, does anyone know the shortcut key to create a new folder on the desktop?

(I'm using windows vista and mac os x)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcut for creating a new folder or file? (Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/13651/keyboard-shortcut-for-creating-a-new-folder-or-file-windows)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Windows**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>: Create a new folder in Windows Explorer.

Alternatively, use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on older Windows versions and <kbd>MENU</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on the desktop.

**Mac OS X**

Create a New Folder shortcut using the System Preferences -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Keyboard Shortcuts panel. The system won't let you choose <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>, but it will let you choose <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>. Use that.

**Desktop**

The shortcut key should work there too.

Comment: Ctrl Shift N isn't working for me (vista here)

Comment: @Pacerier: Ah, apparently [you need `ALT+FWF` there](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/hotkey-for-creating-new-folder-in-windows-explorer/).

Comment: @TomWijsman but its not working on desktop..

Comment: @Pacerier: On the desktop you need to use `MENU+WF`.

Comment: @Tom I thought Cmd+Shift+N was default anyway on OS X

Comment: @Tom Wijsman i don't get it.. what's the menu button?

Comment: @Pacerier: The button that opens a right click menu.

Answer (score 1):

**On Windows 10**
Windows 10 offers an alternative way that I just found. You can configure it yourself. It was standard setting on my system so most people might already have it working this way.
Then the shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (note not <kbd>F2</kbd>)

This refers to the index of the items at the top bar of the windows explorer:
[image]

It can be configured by clicking the arrow next to it to show the item on top (screen shot from german system):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have created an autohotkey script to remap Ctrl+Shift+n to Capslock+F12. 
You can remap it to any other key you want.

The key below is context-sensitive, meaning it will only work in Windows Explorer AND Windows Explorer file dialogs (open/save as).

```
#IfWinActive AHK_CLASS #32770
    Capslock & f12::
#IfWinActive AHK_CLASS CabinetWClass
    Capslock & f12::
    Send {Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}{n}{Shift Up}{Ctrl Up}
    return
#IfWinActive
```

To understand the syntax above, see below example,

```
;   Syntax - To have the same hotkey subroutine executed by more than one variant, the easiest way is to create a stack of identical hotkeys, each with a different #IfWin directive above it. For example:
    ;#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
    ;#z::
    ;#IfWinActive ahk_class WordPadClass
    ;#z::
    ;MsgBox You pressed Win+Z in either Notepad or WordPad.
    ;return
```

Hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut for creating a new folder or file? (Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/13651/keyboard-shortcut-for-creating-a-new-folder-or-file-windows) and have flagged it as such, but seeing as this question is so old and has more views, I figured I could help more people by sharing [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1543125/89165) here:

The built-in Windows Explorer <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> shortcut hasn't worked for me for years. If you Google this, you can find lots of people in similar boats. Perhaps there's some app I'm using that is eating the keystrokes, but I've never been able to find it.

[Once I found this trick](https://superuser.com/a/1543125/89165), I decided to create an [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (v1) script to make <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> work correctly again:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Explorer.exe
+^N::
SendInput {Blind}{Ctrl up}{Shift up}{Alt up}{n up}
SendInput {Blind}{Alt}2
```

Here's the line by line explanation:

1. If Explorer.exe is the active window
2. And you press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
3. "Key up" <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> so they don't interfere with the next line.
4. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>

You can put this script in a ".ahk" file and double click it to start it. [Follow these instructions to have it run automatically when Windows starts.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd)