# Can I make "F1" as the "Create New Folder" shortcut key in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hotkeys

Can I make "F1" as the *Create New Folder* shortcut key in Windows 7?

Also can I customize Windows key shortcuts?

Answer (score 6):

Hm. I don't think there's a way to do that without installing third party utilities. You can create customized keyboard shortcuts to open a shortcut to a folder or application ... Right click on a shortcut, click properties, and put in the shortcut you want. F keys work, or pressing a letter or number key will put in "ctrl + alt + *"

Comment: You can assign a shortcut to respond to just "F1" (no ctrl, alt, shift, etc.).

Comment: Mmm, you're right my bad. I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, try [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll elaborate on @Urinprobe's answer by providing a working AutoHotKey v1 script, potentially saving hours of effort:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Explorer.exe
F1::
SendInput {Blind}{F1 up}
SendInput {Blind}{Alt}2
```

Here's the line by line explanation:

1. If Explorer.exe is the active window
2. And you press <kbd>F1</kbd>
3. "Key up" <kbd>F1</kbd> so it doesn't interfere with the next line.
4. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> ([Here's why this creates a new folder.](https://superuser.com/a/1543125/89165))

You can put this script in a ".ahk" file and double click it to start it. [Follow these instructions to have it run automatically when Windows starts.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd)